# Double Integral: Change of variable - New space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Defining $u=x^2+y^2$, $v=x^2+y^2-2y$, I want to calculate $\iint_D xe^y dxdy$ using the change of variable, where $D$is the space that is determined by the inequalities $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2\geq 2y$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have the new variables $u=x^2+y^2$, $v=x^2+y^2-2y$.

When we solve for $x,y$ as a function of $u,v$ we get: 
$$v=x^2+y^2-2y\Rightarrow v=u-2y \Rightarrow y=\frac{u}{2}-\frac{v}{2}$$ 
$$u=x^2+y^2 \Rightarrow x^2=u-y^2 \Rightarrow x^2=u-\left (\frac{u-v}{2}\right )^2  \Rightarrow x^2=u-\frac{u^2-2uv+v^2}{4} \\ \Rightarrow x^2=\frac{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}{4} \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}{4}}\\ \Rightarrow x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}{2}$$ Since $x\geq 0$ we get $x= \frac{\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}{2}$.

Is everything correct so far?

Now we have to calculate the determinant, right? We get 
\begin{align*}det \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}} \\ \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}}\end{pmatrix}&=det \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2-u+v}{2\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}} & \frac{u-v}{2\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}} \\ \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} \\ & =-\frac{2-u+v}{4\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}-\frac{u-v}{4\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}} \\ & =-\frac{2-u+v+u-v}{4\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}} \\ & =-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}\end{align*}

Therefore we get the following: 
\begin{align*}\iint_D xe^y dxdy&=\iint_E \frac{\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}{2}e^{\frac{u-v}{2}} \left |\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u,v)}}\right |dudv \\ & =\iint_E \frac{\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}{2}e^{\frac{u-v}{2}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4u-u^2+2uv-v^2}}dudv \\ & =\frac{1}{4}\iint_E e^{\frac{u-v}{2}}dudv\end{align*}

Is the new space $E=\{(u,v) \mid 0\leq u\leq 1, 0\leq v\leq 1\}$ ?

I thought so because of the following:

Since $x^2+y^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow u\leq 1$. Since $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$ we have that $x^2+y^2\geq 0$ and so $u\geq 0$.

Since $x^2+y^2\geq 2y \Rightarrow v\geq 0$. Since $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $y\geq 0$ we have that $x^2+y^2-2y\leq 1-2\cdot 0=1$ and so $0\leq v\leq 1$.

Comment: What's your final answer?

Comment: I found the answer $2-e^{\frac{1}{2}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ but at the solution the answer is $e^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{3}{2}$. @MyGlasses

Comment: So, the space $E$ as I defined it is not correct, is it? @MyGlasses

Comment: Very hard area you have selected. Perhaps $E$ isn't rectangle!

Comment: What $E$ did you find? @MyGlasses

Comment: I didn't pursue your solution. At least I know $0\leq y\leq1$ so $v\leq u\leq1+v$. so with this I think perhaps $E$ isn't rectangle!

Comment: We have the following: 
$$2y\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow 2y\leq 1\Rightarrow y\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ 
Therefore we get $$0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow 0\leq \frac{u-v}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow 0\leq u-v\leq 1 \Rightarrow -u\leq -v\leq 1-u \Rightarrow u-1\leq v\leq u$$ 

And from $0\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1$ we get $0\leq u\leq 1$. 

Is this correct? Using that bounds I got $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}}-1}{2}$. @MyGlasses

Comment: At the exercise statement we have the inequalities $x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2\geq 2y$. Can that not be correct? @MyGlasses

Comment: Why did you drop minus in Jacobian?

Comment: I think this is better. $v=x^2+y^2-2y\geq0$, $v=x^2+y^2-2y\leq x^2+y^2\leq1$, $u=v+2y\geq v$ and $u\leq1$ so
$$\frac{1}{4} \int _0^1\int _v^1e^{\frac{u-v}{2}}dudv=\sqrt{e}-\dfrac32$$

Comment: Ahh ok!! Thank you so much!! :-) @MyGlasses

Comment: About the jacobian, we take the absolute value, right?@MyGlasses

Comment: OK. Why didn't use polar substitution?

Comment: According to the exercise we have to use the variables $u,v$ as defined in my initial post. @MyGlasses